# Apache IPv4 deny directive blocks IPv6 addresses

Tags: apache-2.2, blocking

**Edit**
I have thought that excessive number of "deny" lines are confusing apache into blocking unlisted IPv4 addresses. But comment of @Ladadadada made me pinpoint the exact issue. You can read my old question below. The problem is, the following line:

```
deny from 42.1.0.0/19
```

blocks the IPv6 addresses

```
2a01:4f8:120:8201::2
2a01:1e8:e100:ce::2
```

How is this possible?

---

I have a *really* long list of blocked IP addresses, activated by an `Include` directive inside the `Directory` block.

This file only contains IPv4 addresses, but my server is also blocking a **limited** number of IPv6 addresses. It's not blocking all IPv6 traffic. If I remove the blocks, those IPv6 addresses can access the server just fine.

Originally the block file had each IP block on a separate "deny from" line. I tried combining every 40 of them to reduce the rule count and file size. It still did not help.
But when I truncated the rules to 4-5 deny lines, it worked as expected and did not block the IPv6 addresses.

These are sample logs from access log.

```
2a01:4f8:120:8201::2 - - [03/Mar/2013:15:01:07 +0200] "GET /tdf/ HTTP/1.1" 403 387 "-" "MirrorBrain Probe (see http://mirrorbrain.org/probe_info)"
```

and from error log

```
[Sun Mar 03 15:01:07 2013] [error] [client 2a01:4f8:120:8201::2] client denied by server configuration: /mirror/pub/tdf/
```

How can I list a large number of "deny" directives ?  I cannot control the firewall of the machine, so it's out of the question.

Comment: Can you narrow it down to the single line that's blocking the IPv6 address above and include that line in the question?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I thought It was because of the number of blocked IP blocks. Now it seems that there is a single rule that's blocking the IPv6 IPs. I'm trying to pinpoint it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Driving straight into the details, let's convert both `42.1.0.0` and `2a01:1e8` into binary (you'll see why I only chose the initial portion in a moment.)

```
0010 1010 . 0000 0001 . 000 |
   42     .     1     . 0   |

0010 1010   0000 0001 : 000 | 0 0001 1110 1000
         2a01         :     |  1e8
                            |
                            ^ cut here
```

The way CIDR notiation works, is it'll match the first `/X` bits. In your case, it'll match the first `19`, which `2a01:1e8:...` also matches.

This leads me to believe it's a bug, since this is exactly the usage demonstrated in their [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_access.html).

Comment: You are right. Here is the bug which was fixed 3 months ago. https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54047